# Can I do an inclusive du, as opposed to exclusive?

Tags: linux, shell, du

I need to do a du search that only grabs certain subfolders.  For example, here is the directory structure:

```
du -b

0   ./678  
21  ./679/536/Content_Repository_PoC_-_Main  
73  ./Content_Repository_PoC_-_C-CDN_JIT_Packaging/679/536  
255034  ./PoC_-_C-CDN_JIT_Packaging/680/13/processed_3348d8a9-a  
201034  ./PoC_-_C-CDN_JIT_Packaging/683/13/processed_cec582f5-1  
208034  ./PoCx/225/processed_cec27825-1
```

I need it to return the sum total ONLY of the subfolders with the word "processed" in the subfolder name (so in this example, only the bottom three).  I can expect a massive number of positive results.

In other words, rather than `du --exclude='processed*'`, I would want something like

```
du --exclude!='processed*'
```

Answer (score 0):

With find:

```
find -type d -name 'processed*' exec du {} \;
```

If you want the total size:

```
find -type d -name 'processed*' exec du -c {} +
```

('+' has all the matching files processed with one single command)

If all your 'processed*' are at the same directory level you can also avoid find with some shells (bash, zsh):

```
du -c */*/processed*
```

Comment: Thank you, but with that find command I received "find: Arguments to -type should contain only one letter."  I should note this is on Red Hat Enterprise 6.6.

Comment: I actually ended up getting it to work with a modified "find -name processed* -exec du -bs {} +"

Comment: Fixed the commands... mean `find -type d`